# Restricting user to create proxy of asmx web services

Tags: web-services, proxy, asmx

I have a web application. Inside web application I have webservice. asmx file. 
The web service methods I am calling though $. Ajax.

I Restricted user with direct access .asmx web services though browser.

Now my requirement is restricting user to create a proxy of .asmx web services (so that not able to add web reference and so on...).

Could you please provide a solution for that. So that only application can assess this webservice.asmx.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of above requirement is :

```
<webServices>
<protocols>
<remove name="Documentation"/>
</protocols>
</webServices>
```